# Adding a color bar to a chord diagram in python plotly

Tags: python, plotly, colorbar, chord-diagram

I need help figuring out how to add a color bar to a chord diagram I have made. I would like to add a color bar such as in a [heat map](https://plot.ly/~PythonPlotBot/833.png) but in a [chord diagram](https://plot.ly/~chelsea_lyn/9611/a-circular-graph-associated-to-eurovision-song-contest-2015-data-source-1.png), not to be confused with a filled chord diagram in python plotly.

I tried to put in more links and pictures but I guess I need more reputation :( The heat map link is plot.ly/python/heatmaps. The chord diagram is at plot.ly/python/chord-diagram. The filled chord diagram is at plot.ly/python/filled-chord-diagram.

The way in which I plan to use the heat map is to have each line on the chord diagram be a certain color based on the data. For example, if the data says the line has a value of 80, it would be red like in the heat map. If the data said 50, it would be an orange-ish yellow, like in the heat map.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, @Maximilian Peters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your values for your color are stored in a list called `my_weights`.

```
my_weights = [random.random() for _ in E]
```

where E is a list of edges.

We can then add a trace which only has the purpose of drawing the colorbar. Its markers are hidden behind one of the nodes.

```
color_trace = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=[0 for _ in my_weights],
                                        y=[0 for _ in my_weights],
                                        mode='markers',
                                        marker=plotly.graph_objs.Marker(
                                            colorscale=[
                                                [c / 100.0, 'rgba({}, {}, {}, {})'.format(*color_range(c / 100.0))] for
                                                c in range(101)],
                                            size=1,
                                            color=my_weights,
                                            showscale=True,
                                            )
                                        )
```

For the colorscale we can use `matplotlib` to get a [custom color generator](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps).

```
color_range = plt.get_cmap('OrRd')
```

The complete code is based on the example [here](https://plot.ly/python/chord-diagram/) and produces the following graph.

[image]

---

```
import igraph as ig
import numpy as np
import plotly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

color_range = plt.get_cmap('OrRd')


def dist(a, b):
    return np.linalg.norm(np.array(a) - np.array(b))


def get_idx_interv(d, D):
    k = 0
    while d > D[k]:
        k += 1
    return k - 1


def deCasteljau(b, t):
    n = len(b)
    a = np.copy(b)  # shallow copy of the list of control points
    for r in range(1, n):
        a[:n - r, :] = (1 - t) * a[:n - r, :] + t * a[1:n - r + 1, :]
    return a[0, :]


def bezierCv(b, nr=5):
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, nr)
    return np.array([deCasteljau(b, t[k]) for k in range(nr)])


G = ig.Graph.Read_GML('Eurovision15.gml')

V = list(G.vs)
G.vs.attributes()
labels = [v['label'] for v in V]
E = [e.tuple for e in G.es]
ContestantLst = [G.vs[e[2]] for e in E]
Contestant = list(set([v['label'] for v in ContestantLst]))
layt = G.layout('circular')
Weights = map(int, G.es["weight"])

Dist = [0, dist([1, 0], 2 * [np.sqrt(2) / 2]), np.sqrt(2),
        dist([1, 0], [-np.sqrt(2) / 2, np.sqrt(2) / 2]), 2.0]
params = [1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1]

node_color = ['rgba(0,51,181, 0.85)' if v['label'] in Contestant else '#CCCCCC' for v in G.vs]
line_color = ['#FFFFFF' if v['label'] in Contestant else 'rgb(150,150,150)' for v in G.vs]
edge_colors = ['#d4daff', '#84a9dd', '#5588c8', '#6d8acf']

L = len(layt)

Xn = [layt[k][0] for k in range(L)]
Yn = [layt[k][2] for k in range(L)]

lines = list()
edge_info = list()
my_weights = [random.random() for _ in E]

for j, e in enumerate(E):
    A = np.array(layt[e[0]])
    B = np.array(layt[e[2]])
    d = dist(A, B)
    K = get_idx_interv(d, Dist)
    b = [A, A / params[K], B / params[K], B]
    color = edge_colors[K]
    pts = bezierCv(b)
    text = V[e[0]]['label'] + ' to ' + V[e[2]]['label'] + ' ' + str(Weights[j]) + ' pts'
    mark = deCasteljau(b, 0.9)
    edge_info.append(plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=mark[0],
                                               y=mark[2],
                                               mode='markers',
                                               marker=plotly.graph_objs.Marker(size=0.5, color=edge_colors),
                                               text=text,
                                               hoverinfo='text'
                                               )
                     )

    lines.append(plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=pts[:, 0],
                                           y=pts[:, 1],
                                           mode='lines',
                                           line=plotly.graph_objs.Line(
                                               color='rgba({}, {}, {}, {})'.format(*color_range(my_weights[j])),
                                               shape='spline',
                                               width=Weights[j] / 5),
                                           hoverinfo='none')
                 )

trace2 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=Xn,
                                   y=Yn,
                                   mode='markers',
                                   marker=plotly.graph_objs.Marker(symbol='dot',
                                                                   size=15,
                                                                   color=node_color,
                                                                   line=plotly.graph_objs.Line(color=line_color,
                                                                                               width=0.5)
                                                                   ),
                                   text=labels,
                                   hoverinfo='text'
                                   )

color_trace = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=[0 for _ in my_weights],
                                        y=[0 for _ in my_weights],
                                        mode='markers',
                                        marker=plotly.graph_objs.Marker(
                                            colorscale=[
                                                [c / 100.0, 'rgba({}, {}, {}, {})'.format(*color_range(c / 100.0))] for
                                                c in range(101)],
                                            size=1,
                                            color=my_weights,
                                            showscale=True,
                                            )
                                        )

axis = dict(showline=False,
            zeroline=False,
            showgrid=False,
            showticklabels=False,
            title=''
            )

layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(showlegend=False,
                                  autosize=False,
                                  width=800,
                                  height=850,
                                  xaxis=plotly.graph_objs.XAxis(axis),
                                  yaxis=plotly.graph_objs.YAxis(axis),
                                  margin=plotly.graph_objs.Margin(l=40,
                                                                  r=40,
                                                                  b=85,
                                                                  t=100,
                                                                  ),
                                  hovermode='closest')

data = plotly.graph_objs.Data([color_trace] + lines + edge_info + [trace2])
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='Eurovision-15.html')
```